# In Swift, why do I get an error when trying to Println textfield.text

Tags: ios, swift

I know it gives me an 'explanation,' but I still don't really understand it.

I'm trying to print the contents of my UITextField each time it's updated.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func textUpdated(sender: UITextField) {
        println("textFieldtext = %@", sender.text);
}
```

I get an error: `Cannot invoke 'println' with an argument list of type '(StringLiteralConvertible, @Ivalue String!)'`

What does that mean? What can I do to print this?

Comment: Try `println("textFieldText = \(sender.text)")`

Comment: Sidenote: a semi-colon in you code is fine but is frowned upon. It is best practice not to use semi-colons to terminate a line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this instead:

`println("textFieldText = \(sender.text)")`

This is called [String Interopelation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292) and it allows you to build a new string from various different types. The way you are doing it doesn't work because println only takes one argument.

EDIT: Added an explanation based on the info from the comments.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy: could you be a bit more verbose as to what the parentheses and \ do in this instance? I'm trying to understand this moving forward, and not do things 'just because that's the way you do them.'

Comment: What I'm doing is called string Interpolation. It basically allows you to construct a new string by passing in various variables with types that can be converted to a String with a `description` method. To be honest I'm not entirely sure why your way of doing it is no working, but I will look into it.

Comment: OP's code does  not compile because println() takes a *single* argument, not *multiple* arguments as NSLog  in Objective-C or printf in C.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at println' signature and it looks like you're right Martin.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; it's making a bit more sense now.

Comment: @Adama [Here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292) for String Interpolation.